# Simplify Equation with Unknown Vectors and Known Magnitudes

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm stuck on a problem from my Calculus III class

Simplify the following expression if
$\ ||v|| = 8$ and $\ ||w|| = 8$

$\ (v + w) · (v + w) − 2v · w$

It's wanting a numerical answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
(v+w)\cdot(v+w) -2 v\cdot w 
 &= v\cdot v + v \cdot w + w \cdot v + w \cdot w - 2v\cdot w\\
 & = v \cdot v + w\cdot w\\
 &= |v||v| \cos 0^\circ + |w||w|\cos 0^\circ & &\text{by definition}\\
 &= |v|^2 + |w|^2\\
 &= 8^2 + 8^2\\
 &= 64+64\\
 &=128
\end{align}

Comment: It never occurred to me that the distributive property was applicable to the dot product... Thanks very much

Comment: @David: If $v\cdot w$ does not vanish in the given expression then you need the smallest angle $\theta$ between the two vectors because by definition $v\cdot w=|v||w|\cos \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand  the dot product $(v+w)\cdot(v+w)$. We have 
$$(v+w)\cdot(v+w)=v\cdot(v+w)+w\cdot(v+w)=v\cdot v +v\cdot w+w\cdot v+w\cdot w.$$
The expression on the right is $v\cdot v+w\cdot w+2v\cdot w$.

Comment: It never occurred to me that the distributive property was applicable to the dot product... Thanks very much

Comment: You are welcome. It is not hard to check distributivity for the usual dot product, and it is part of the *definition* of general dot product.